# Will PTR records for IP's that relay mail?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I am having some spam issues with my mail server.

I have multiple servers that are relaying mail through my mail server. I am wanting to know if PTR records for these servers will have any effect with regards to recipient mail servers marking mail as spam?

Comment: I don't think I follow. In this case, aren't *you* the recipient mail server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naw... The PTR records for the other servers shouldn't matter. You'll pretty much only need reverse PTR records on the relay server.

Please make sure you limit *who* can relay through that server. You want to avoid having an [open relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay).

If those other servers are sending spam or have been compromised, what they send can affect the reputation of your relay server. That *can* affect your spam ranking.